# Dealing with millions of data records in MySQL and PHP/Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, performance, laravel, search

I have an activity records table named **revisions** (showed in following image) built for a big learning management system, which mainly keeps record of CRUD operations on tables (e.g. who has done what on which object in what time).

[image: revisions table]

This table may contain up to 3M records of data. I want to build a search functionality for this on the front-end with PHP/Laravel.

**Now my question is that** what things should I consider for building search functionalities with high performance for tables with millions of records of data, what are the things on code level, database level, or are there 3rd party stuff to support these kind of issues?

I am experienced with building systems with PHP/Laravel, Python/Django, Ruby, etc. But I have never encountered with a case like this, dealing with millions records of data. So please keep in mind my knowledge/experience level. I have NO experience on this level.

**Note:** Search will be an advance search, making users able to search with different criteria and parameters, the object which is changed, who has changed it, when it's changed, etc.

Let me know if my question still isn't clear.

Comment: While your question is pretty clear, it is both very broad and will attract opinion based answers, making it off topic for this site. I'm voting to close it.

Comment: Well this is kinda question that has to be broad. Can you explain where can I ask it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend to take a look at the https://www.elastic.co/products/elasticsearch and save your activity records to its storage when you do save to the main database. Then you can easily search any field. Elasticsearch can store a schema free JSON documents, if you prefer more SQL way, there is another search engine - http://sphinxsearch.com/.

Comment: So in case if I use elasticsearch, the CRUD operations needs to be done on both? my MySQL DB and Elasticsearch instance?

Comment: Yes. Laravel has special model listeners http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#events so you can easily CRUD data in the other storages when you are changing base model object

Answer (score 4):

There is no problem inserting a zillion rows into a table.  Performance problems come when you try to do non-trivial SELECTs on the table.  You mentioned "search"; you will have to limit what the 'users' can search for.  But at least make a stab at what they *might* want to search for.

You mentioned "searching for an object", but I don't see a column called object.  How many rows might there be for a given object?  Do you need all the rows?  Or selected ones?  (An INDEX on object is likely to make the query efficient, regardless of table size.)

Third-party software sometimes gets in the way of dealing with really large tables.  Beware.